# java installation in RHEL

Tags: rhel, java

while installing java in redhat i'm facing some problems..i've attached the screen print.
[image]

i unzipped the file using tar command .once i created the softlink for it ,i should be able to see java version and all but which in this case i'm not able to see

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, paste the *actual text*...

Comment: Where did you install Java? I've got no experience with RHEL, but my first guess would be that you installed java in a place not known to the system.

Comment: Why not just install the Java RPM package via `yum` or `dnf` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have extracted the jdk-7-linux-x64.tar.gz file to the "jdk" directory. Now, inside this directory, you will find a directory called "bin". And the "java" binary would resides at this location.

So, add the below lines to the file ~/.bash_profile file with the logged in user (in our current scenario abhishek).

```
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/Desktop/jdk    
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Save the file and run the below command at the command prompt.

```
$ cd 
$ . .bash_profile
```

Now, run the below commands for knowing where from the java is being picked

```
$ which java
$ java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```

and then do,

```
java -version
```

For more inputs, refer [redhat manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Installation_Guide/Install_OpenJDK_on_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux.html)